# How to get list of deleted or deactivated user from AWS IAM

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam, identity-management

Is there any way I can get a list of removed or deleted user in AWS ? All I am getting is list of users who all are active but I need a list of removed user.
I have tried to get logs out of cloud trail but could not find the relevant event.
I not much familiar with AWS maybe because of this I could not find any module for this.
Thank you

Comment: Deleted urer or iam user? Because iam user and account are 2 different things

Comment: Hey @JatinMehrotra, Its IAM user.

Comment: Posted a solution, hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can able to find out the delete user with the following eventName in the AWS Cloudtrail.

**"eventName:DeleteUser"**

However by default, the AWS Cloudtrail has only past 90 days activities only.

Comment: And also eventName AdminDeleteUser

Answer (score 0):

To search for deleted IAM users visit CloudTrail Events and filter results with  **eventName:DeleteUser** and/or **eventName:AdminDeleteUser** filters.

For searching users deleted more than 90 days ago you have to create a CloudTrail trail (and enabling CloudWatch Logs is recommended).

**Tip: Because IAM is a global resource, you have to set your region on to us-east-1 (North Virginia) or your queries do not return any results for those events.**